# Selenium Python получение кол-ва элементов по xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Пишу небольшой наглядный парсер через selenium на языке Python. Моя программа заходит на сайт, авторизуется, считывает нужный мне блок, анализирует, идет дальше. Происходит это таким вот образом

```
while i<25:
    s1 = '(//span[@class="wo-subject"])['
    s2 = ']'
    i = str(i)
    s = s1+i+s2
    name = driver.find_element_by_xpath(s).text
    ...
    i = int(i)
    i = i+1
```

Таких блоков на самом деле не 25, а как сначала узнать, сколько элементов по моему условию xpath я не догадался и найти не могу. Поэтому прошу у вас помощи. Как мне узнать, сколько элементов на странице подходят под моё условие

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various strategies to locate elements in a page. You can use the most appropriate one for your case. Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector
```

To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):

```
find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Да, мне это помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Русский стековерфлоу - ответы надо на русском давать